# Mailkit POP3: get attachment text without headers

Tags: vb.net, email-attachments, pop3, mailkit, mimekit

I download POP3 messages with a CSV file attached.
I need to get the plain text in the attachment and I do this like:

```
For Each BP As MimeKit.MimeEntity In Msg.BodyParts
   'Filtering:
   If Not BP.IsAttachment = True Then Continue For
   If Not BP.ContentDisposition.FileName.EndsWith(".csv") Then Continue For

   Console.WriteLine((DirectCast(BP, MimeKit.TextPart).Text))
Next
```

This work if

```
BP.ContentType.MediaType = "text"
BP.ContentType.MimeType = "csv"
```

But if e.g. `MediaType = application` I cannot cast the `BodyPart` to `TextPart` and get access to the `.Text` property.

I can get the full attachment-text using `BP.ToString` but it return everything incl. headers:

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;
name="MyFile.csv"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename="MyFile.csv"

2018-03-10 10:12;0.797;m3/h;1.8;-0.3;1.8;m3;0.000;0.000;96;5346=0A=
2018-03-10 10:13;0.820;m3/h;1.8;-0.3;1.8;m3;0.000;0.000;96;5346=0A=
2018-03-10 10:14;0.868;m3/h;1.9;-0.3;1.9;m3;0.000;0.000;96;5346=0A=
2018-03-10 10:15;0.549;m3/h;1.9;-0.3;1.9;m3;0.000;0.000;96;5346=0A=
2018-03-10 10:16;0.281;m3/h;1.9;-0.3;1.9;m3;0.000;0.000;96;5346=0A=
```

1: How can I get the attachment-text of the bodypart no matter the value in `ContentType..`

2: I download the whole mail/attachment before doing my filtering. How can I download only the attachment-headers to be used in my filtering?

Answer (score 1):

The generic way of getting the content of a MimePart look like this in c# (sorry, I don’t know VB):

```
using (var memory = new MemoryStream ()) {
    part.Content.DecodeTo (memory);

    var buffer = memory.ToArray ();
    var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (buffer);
}
```

Comment: I also tried that, that will still give you everything incl. headers.
There must be a mime method that divide the attachment part in objects: headers and content...but cannot find it. 
The `MimeKit.TextPart.Text` does this, but only work with some mails

Comment: ..to be accurate I tried `part.WriteTo(memory)` I assume it does the same. I don't have `part.Content`

Comment: Make sure to cast to MimePart, then you’ll have a Content property. And no, it is not the same as part.WriteTo().

Comment: It works perfectly  :-)
Could I have read somewhere in the documentation that you can cast to MimePart?